# Enable to display jcombobox after filling some jtextfields

Tags: java, mysql, database, jtextfield, jcombobox

I've a form wich contains some textfields and jcomboxes. The first Jcombox contains names of groups ( **libelle_groupe** in my code) and the other one : status value ( **valeur** in my code). After choosing a jcombobox value, i try to get id of both group and status from my database to insert into this table : compte_utilisateur. The jcomboboxes are the last ones in my form. Before touching any of the textfields, i can choose from the comboboxes values. But onces, one of the textfields is touched, i can't choose anymore values from both jcomboboxes. Does any one know why? 
here is my code to fill combo box from database:

```
private void FillCombo(){

PreparedStatement pst=null;

    ResultSet rs=null;

try{

   String sql="select * from groupe";

     pst=  (PreparedStatement) maConnexion.ObtenirConnexion().prepareStatement(sql);

     rs=pst.executeQuery();

   while(rs.next()){

   String libelle_groupe=rs.getString("id_groupe");

combo_name.addItem(libelle_groupe);

}

}

catch(Exception e){ JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);}

}
```

code to insert data into my db :

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    PreparedStatement pst=null;


    try {
String requete="INSERT INTO compte_utilisateur(Id_compte, Nom, Prenom, Matricule, Id_groupe, Id_statut) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
       pst=maConnexion.ObtenirConnexion().prepareStatement(requete);

    pst.setString(1, jTIdf.getText());
    pst.setString(2, jTNom.getText());
    pst.setString(3, jTPrenom.getText());
    pst.setString(4, jTMatricule.getText());
    String comb1=combo_name.getSelectedItem().toString();
    pst.setString(5, comb1);
    String comb2=jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
    pst.setString(6, comb2);

    pst.execute();
}
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace(); } 
}
```

Comment: Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. We don't have access to you database you your SSCCE will need to simulate the database query by using hardcoded data. Once you get that working then you add the SQL back to the code. This way you know if the problem is with the SQL or some other code. We can't help based on the random lines of code posted.

Comment: I edited my question, the prob is not with sql but with combo box, cuz when i choose first values from combo boxes and then fill textfields, the data is correctly inserted in my database. And even, when i fill the textfields first, the combo boxes dont allow me to chose and add to my database the value shown.

Comment: Can anyone help please

Comment: `Can anyone help please` - you haven't given us anything to work with. A verbal description doesn't help because the problem is with your code and you haven't posted a `SSCCE` yet.

Comment: Okay what should I do exactly ? I read about SSCCE but i don't know what should I do exactly

Comment: You create a simple program that demonstrates the problem so we can execute the code so see if we have the same behaviour.